# react-admin SelectField Clearing Value onChange

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a Create form where another SelectInput is made visible depending on the selection of another SelectInput.

The first time this happens, the first input is cleared.  How do I stop the first select from clearing?

[image: RecreateExample]

Here is the code to recreate:

```
import {Create, SelectInput, TextInput, SimpleForm} from 'react-admin';
import React from 'react';

class Recreate extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props = props;
    this.state = {visible: false}

}

render() {
    return (

        <Create {...this.props}>
            <SimpleForm>
                <SelectInput source="device" choices={[{id: 'OR', name: 'Oregon'}, {id: 'WA', name: 'Washington'}]}
                             onChange={(event, key, payload) => this.setState({visible: key === 'WA'})}

                />
                {this.state.visible &&  (
                    <SelectInput label={'I am visible from WA'}
                                 source="renderer"
                                 choices={[
                                     {id: 'Seattle', name: 'Seattle'},
                                     {id: 'Olympia', name: 'Olympia'},
                                 ]}
                                 defaultValue={'gs'}/>
                )}
            </SimpleForm>
        </Create>


    );
}
```

}

export default Recreate;

**Update:  Attempted fix based on answers:**

```
import {Create, SelectInput, SimpleForm, TextInput} from 'react-admin';
import React from 'react';

const CustomSelectInput = ({onChangeCustomHandler, ...rest}) => (
    <SelectInput onChange={(event, key, payload) => {
        onChangeCustomHandler(key)
    }}
             {...rest}
    />
);

class Recreate extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props = props;
    this.state = {visible: false}

}

render() {
    return (

        <Create {...this.props}>
            <SimpleForm>
                <CustomSelectInput source="device"
                                   choices={[{id: 'OR', name: 'Oregon'}, {id: 'WA', name: 'Washington'}]}
                                   onChangeCustomHandler={(key) => this.setState({visible: key === 'WA'})}/>

                {this.state.visible && (
                    <SelectInput label={'I am visible from WA'}
                                 source="renderer"
                                 choices={[
                                     {id: 'Seattle', name: 'Seattle'},
                                     {id: 'Olympia', name: 'Olympia'},
                                 ]}
                                 />
                )}
            </SimpleForm>
        </Create>


    );
}
}

export default Recreate;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first input is cleared probably because you override its `onChange` prop without calling the original one which is injected transparently by `SimpleForm`.

You'll need to introduce a custom `SelectDeviceInput` component which will wrap the original `SelectInput`, handle its `onChange` event and call another `onXXX` prop you can pass in the same handle. Set your state in the handler you'll pass to this `onXXX` prop inside the `Recreate` component.

**NOTE**: Your custom `SelectDeviceInput` will receive an `input` prop with the `onChange` handler you must call for redux-form to work. See https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/field.md/#1-a-component

That's one side effect of `SimpleForm` doing a `cloneElement` of its children to ease its usage.

Comment: I need to show the second select based on a state value, something that is not available in the record.  Can the ShowController still help in this case?

Comment: Isn't `device`part of the record ?

Comment: This is a sscce - ish example.  The real code fetches the selected device, looks at the deviceType, then display several device specific inputs based on the device type.  All that was too much to post, so I tried to boil it down to something smaller.  Hope that helps and thanks for looking.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Excellent, I will try this out and post back.

Comment: Ok, I tried it but obviously did something wrong.  Posting as an answer below since it is too long for a comment

Comment: Posted update above. Made a custom SelectDeviceInput, but did not know how to forward the onChange appropriately.  Updated state in custom onXXX prop though.  Form works but same behavior.

Comment: Added an important note about this

Answer (score 0):

If someone still facing with the above problem, below is my code. The solution provided by @Yvette and @Gildas is working pefectly fine.

```
const CustomSelectInput = ({ onChangeCustomHandler, ...rest }) => (
    <SelectInput onChange={(event, key, payload) => {
        onChangeCustomHandler(key)
    }}
        {...rest}
    />
);

export class Create extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.headers = new Headers({
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
        this.state = {
            doctors: [],
            hospitals: [],
            visible: false,
        }
        this.handleOnchange = this.handleOnchange.bind(this);
    }

    handleOnchange(key) { 
        fetch(`URL/${key}`, {
            method: "get",
            headers: this.headers,
        }).then(response => response.json()).then(res => this.setState({ hospitals: res.data, visible: true }));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`URL to fetch data`, {
            method: "get",
            headers: this.headers,
        }).then(response => response.json()).then(res => this.setState({ doctors: res.data }));
    }
    render() {
        const {
            hospitals,
            doctors,
            visible
        } = this.state;

        let hospitalsArr = hospitals.map((hospital) => {
            return {
                id: hospital.id,
                name: hospital.hospital_name
            }
        });

        let doctorsArr = doctors.map((doctor) => {
            return (
                {
                    id: doctor.id,
                    name: `${doctor.user_profile.firstname} ${doctor.user_profile.lastname}`
                }
            )
        });

        return (
            <Create {...this.props}>
                <SimpleForm>

                    <CustomSelectInput source="doctor_id"
                        choices={doctorsArr}
                        onChangeCustomHandler={this.handleOnchange} />

                    {visible ? <SelectInput label="Hospitals" source="hospital_id" choices={hospitalsArr} required /> : null}


                </SimpleForm>
            </Create>
        );
    }
}
```